# Execute Permission on Function not Enough in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

New to Pg from MS SQL side where to restrict access simply grant EXE permission to Functions and SPs. So created a user/role, set its `search_path` to a dedicated schema of a database, grant `EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA myschema`. Tried execute a function got

> permission denied for schema myschema

Ok, `grant usage on schema myschema to role`. The function does a `select ... from mytable` so now

> permission denied for table mytable

To `grant SELECT on my table`? Wait, purpose of this function is to restrict the role from exploring tables.

Comment: Do you expect the code inside the function to run with different permissions than those of the caller? Then you'll have to use `SECURITY DEFINER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation is: User `a` owns a table `mytable` in a schema `myschema`. User `b` initially has no permissions on either. Now you want to allow `b` limited access to `mytable`. Granting `SELECT` on the table would be too much — you want to grant access only through a special function `myfunction`.

Then you need a function that does not run with the permissions of the caller (`SECURITY INVOKER`), which would be the default, but with the permissions of the function owner (`SECURITY DEFINER`). Then user `a` should run:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.read_mytable(...) RETURNS ...
   LANGUAGE ...
   /* runs with the privileges of the owner */
   SECURITY DEFINER
   /* important: force "search_path" to a fixed order */
   SET search_path = pg_catalog,pg_temp
AS $$...$$;

/* by default, everybody can execute a function */
REVOKE EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.read_mytable FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.read_mytable TO b;
```

Note that I created the function in schema `public`, to which `b` has access (don't forget to `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;`!).

Setting a `search_path` for user `b` is not enough, since this can always be changed dynamically with the `SET` command. You don't want `b` to [run a privilege escalation attack](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/).

Comment: Excellent, I'm able to resolve it now without `pg_temp` in the path. What's the benefit of having it?

Comment: [This](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/) is a good article. Wouldn't it be great to change default pg behavior every new funct/sp is granted EXE to public to be explicit permission grant like MS SQL or Oracle? Also `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;` is the default? Last question, any impact if I drop `public` schema?

Comment: That is just the standard order. You can set `search_path` empty with the same effect. The default settings are still there for compatiblity reasons, although efforts for `public` are underway. You can drop the `public` schema, but then you might need another place for extension objects.